# How to find a particular char in string in my case "-" and replace it with "_" in javascript js

Tags: javascript, string, function, replace, char

Hey guys i am currently learning javascript, i need to replace "-" with "_".
For example : "Hello-World" ==> "Hello_World" i tired the below code it didn't work,i want to know why this method is wrong,

```js
function kS(n){ 
    j=n.length;
    for(i=0;i<j;i++){ 
        if(n[i]=="-")
        {
            n[i]="_"; 
            console.log(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: strings are immutable.

Comment: Use a `regex` and `.replace` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurrences of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stings are immutable. You could convert the string to an array of characters and check and replace the item in the `characters` array.

At the end return a joined array.

BTW, spelling matter, eg `length` and undeclared variables are global in Javascript, which should be avoided.

```js
function kS([...characters]) {
    var l = characters.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (characters[i] === "-") characters[i] = "_";
    }
    return characters.join('');
}

console.log(kS('1-2-3'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use replace

```js
console.log("Hello-World".replace('-','_'))
```

Comment: Questions like these should be closed. Please do not answer them :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `String.replace` to achieve that. If you use the regex input in combination with `g` modifier, it will match all occurences. `https://regex101.com/` is a good place to test out such regexes.

```
var myString = "hello-word";
myString = myString.replace(/-/g, '_');
```

If you have to do it with a loop and are allowed to use ES2015 or newer, you could also write it like this:

```
var myString = "hello-word";
var newString = [...myString].map(c => c === '-' ? '_' : c).join('');
```

Comment: Questions like these should be closed. Please do not answer them :)

Comment: @pai.not.pi Until this question is closed, I am in favour of letting people make some rep by adding good answers.